# What is $\frac{\partial Af(A)}{\partial A}$?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

We know that, for scalars, $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$. Does the same hold for vectors wrt matrices, i.e., if $f(A)$ is a vector who depends on $A$, does

$$
\frac{\partial Af(A)}{\partial A} = \frac{\partial A}{\partial A}f(A)+A^T\frac{\partial f(A)}{\partial A}
$$

hold? If not, how do I compute $\frac{\partial Af(A)}{\partial A}$?

Comment: The usual cases of 'matrix differentiation' are the derivative of a matrix function w/r/t a scalar, and derivative of a scalar function w/r/t a matrix. So it's not at all obvious what you even mean by the derivative of a vector function w/r/t a matrix.

Comment: Are you expecting the result of this to be a scalar, vector, matrix, or something else?

Comment: @eyeballfrog I would expect a 3D tensor, but at this point I'm not really sure anymore.

Comment: What about looking at a curve in your space of matrices, A(t), with A(0) = A, and using the chain rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule you are seeking *does exist* for derivatives (with respect to a scalar) and for differentials.
$$\eqalign{
\frac{d\,(f\odot g)}{dx} &= \frac{df}{dx}\odot g &+ f\odot\frac{dg}{dx} \\
d\,(f\odot g) &= df\odot g &+ f\odot dg \\
}$$
where $(\odot)$ represents **any** product (Hadamard, Kronecker, dot, double-dot, dyadic, tensor, etc) and $(f,g)$ can be any scalar, vector, matrix, or tensor which is compatible with that product and $(x)$ is a scalar variable. You can think of the differential as the derivative with respect to a scalar where the scalar variable has not yet been specified. One of its virtues is that it saves a lot of formatting.

For your specific problem, since you told us *nothing* about the function $f$, I'll assume that you already know how to calculate its gradient, i.e.
$${\cal J}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial A} \quad\implies df = {\cal J}:dA$$
Define a new vector function $\,y=Af\;$ and calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
dy &= dA\cdot f + A\cdot df \\
 &= dA\cdot f + A\cdot{\cal J}:dA \\
 &= ({\cal H}\cdot f + A\cdot{\cal J}):dA \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial A} &= {\cal H}\cdot f + A\cdot{\cal J} \\
}$$
In the above, the symbol $(\cdot)$ represents the dot-product and $(:)$ the double-dot product.

The 4th order tensor ${\cal H}$ is the dyadic product of identity matrices: $\,{\cal H}=I\star I$

which can be written in component form using Kronecker delta symbols: $\,{\cal H}_{ijkl} = \delta_{ij}\,\delta_{kl}$

Note that these definitions mean that $\;{\cal H}\cdot f = I\star f$

The 3rd order tensor ${\cal J}$ is left to you to calculate component-wise:
$\;{\cal J}_{ijk} = \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial A_{jk}}$

Answer (score 1):

Whenever there are rank 3 or higher tensors involved, you should use Einstein notation.

If you're expecting a rank 3 tensor, this gives
$$
\frac{\partial Af(A)}{\partial A} = \frac{\partial A_{k\ell}f_\ell(A)}{\partial A_{ij}} = \frac{\partial A_{k\ell}}{\partial A_{ij}}f_\ell(A) + A_{k\ell}\frac{\partial f_\ell(A)}{\partial A_{ij}} = \delta_{ik}f_j(A) + A_{k\ell}\frac{\partial f_\ell(A)}{\partial A_{ij}} .
$$
The expression at the end here could be written as
$$
\frac{\partial Af(A)}{\partial A}= If(A) + A\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial A},
$$
but that would be ambiguous, especially if you start contracting it with other tensors later.

If, on the other hand, you're expecting a vector (most likely by contracting $j$ with $k$ in the previous work), you'd get
$$
\frac{\partial Af(A)}{\partial A}= f_i(A) + A_{j\ell}\frac{\partial f_\ell}{\partial A_{ij}} = f(A) + A:\frac{\partial f}{\partial A},
$$
though this last expression is ambiguous as to what indices are being contracted.